# Resize image as background

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have an image which is 2000x2000 pixels. As I thought the more pixels the better, so less quality loss.
Now i want to show it in my browser as resolution: 500x500.

The image should be as background of a div this is how i've tried to do it:

```
<div id="layer1">
        <div id="house">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

#house {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: url(../images/House.gif);
}
```

there's just a part of the image viewed. I want the whole image to be visable.
I'm using div layer1, as i have lots more details, apart from the house.

Would be glad if anyone can help me on this one

Comment: "the more pixels the better, so less quality loss": If you make the user download a 4x times bigger picture which (s)he actually won't need, then I don't think it's a good choice. I would use resolution-based media queries to give them an image with the appropriate resolution.

Comment: A 2000x2000 GIF image? Your hoster shall be happy.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes what if i'm hosting myself?

Comment: Regardless of who is hosting, your users will still have to download a file that is FAR larger than necessary for the page. An image of 2000px by 2000px will be eight times larger than one at 500px by 500px. This will result is slower page load and higher bills for those on limited tariffs (for example mobile). On mobile devices such as tablets and phones, it will also result in higher battery usage. Do your users a favour and keep the image size down.

Comment: It is also worth considering that there may be image quality loss as the browser scales the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `background-size` property to make the background the exact size of the div.

```
#house {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: url(../images/House.gif);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did the magic for me :)! I will accept in a few minutes as i cannot accept it yet :P

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is by using `background-size` and to change the background of the element to some new value other than the default one.

```
background-size: width height;
```

So by using this, just add a line of code to the group

```
#house {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(../images/House.gif);
  background-size: 500px 500px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/6nGEf/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS or jQuery for doing that:

[CSS Tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

[jQuery plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/responsive-fullscreen-background-image-plugins/)

But 500x500 shouldn't be enough to get a good looking background on many devices